# PHP/MYSQL INSERT multiple rows FROM a TABLE WHERE one criteria using TRANSACTIONS

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

I have to move several rows from one table to another one depending on a column value which is a number.

```
$order_code = '8888';
$conn->autocommit(false);

$sqlTranInsert = "SELECT * FROM shop_inventory WHERE item_order_code ='$order_code'";

if(!$resultTranInsert = $conn->query($sqlTranInsert)){
    echo 'Error '.$conn->error;
    $conn->close();
    exit;
}

while($row = $resultTranInsert->fetch_assoc()){
    $inve_id = $row['inve_id'];
    $sqlTranInsertItems = "INSERT INTO shop_inventory_archive SELECT * FROM shop_inventory WHERE inve_id = '$inve_id'";
    if(!$resultTranInsertItems = $conn->query($sqlTranInsertItems)){
        echo 'Error '.$conn->error;
        $conn->close();
        exit;
    }
}

$conn->commit();
$conn->close();
echo $msg;
exit;
```

My problem is that this is not working at all and I'm not sure about the WHILE loop and I'm sure that there is the problem. Thanks for any help.

Greetings.

Comment: Where do you execute the insert statement in the while loop? You are missing the $conn->query call

Comment: Yep, my bad when I pasted my code. I updated the question.

Comment: Do you get any error from the echo line after the insert in the loop?

Comment: No :( It goes to the $msg which is = 'Orders copied' which is the message as everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

We can copy all columns from one table to another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or we can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't need to paste the whole table or a particular column into another table, I need to Insert into a TABLE 1 several rows from a TABLE 2 depending in a column value which is the same in several rows.